# Localization of a WinForms app and later UI changes

Tags: .net, localization

I am using VS2008 to develop a WinForms 2.0 application. I have read about how to  localize my app in the Visual Studio by setting the Localizable property to true in the designer etc.

I would like to ask about your experience, how does it work when I translate the app into several languages and then make changes to the user interface. For example, I add some buttons, delete some other controls from a form etc. I know it isn't best practice, but sometimes I have to localize the app in the middle of development and then continue to add new features. Does it all work or will I end with some corrupted resource files or such?

The reason I am asking is that I had used Borland C++ Builder before, which had big problems when I changed UI in an already localized app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add controls to your form and set properties they will be added to the culture neutral resources of your form.

When you load the form .NET will try to find the resources for the users specific culture (say nb-NO for norwegian bokmål). If the resource isn't found .NET will try the netural cultrue (NO in this case) and if no resources are found for that either it will load the neutral resource.

So even if you add new controls but don't add culture specific resources for them your application will work but with english (?) texts instead of translated texts.

Comment: Very old question, but I'd like to add this: do not *rename* your components after you've added a second language. That has messed up my form.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of editing localized forms causing problems, after answering questions for 3 years in the MSDN Windows Forms forum.  Microsoft isn't Borland.